# How to use apostrophes in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Why it is jumping to the next line after name?

```
Age=10

Input_name=input('Name')

print(str(Input_name)+"'s age is "+ str(Age))
```

*FINAL OUTPUT AS SHOWN BELOW*

```
name
's age is 10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what does this have to do with apostrophes? your output looks like you just hit the enter key at the input prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you input something into your program, you usually enter a newline character (`\n`) at the end of the input by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To get rid of that, you can use the `strip()` method.

Example:

```
Age=10

Input_name=input('Name').strip("\n")

print(str(Input_name)+"'s age is "+ str(Age))
```

Output:

```
foo's age is 10
```